# MySQL up normal behavior

Tags: mysql

There is a serious issue in Mysql all versions that while executing wrong query it update the one column branch_code to zero. this is the query,

```
update intra_staff set br_code=82 and staff_code=2918
```

look at the syntax of the query its totally wrong where class is missing here so it should give error. but this query executed successfully and updated all the records of the table to zoro which is not mentioned in the query can any one please tell me why is it so.

why all the brach codes upadated to zero which is no where mentioned in the query ?

Comment: There's no syntax error here. Please provide the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE intra_staff` and consider whether you have any triggers running in the background

Answer (score 2):

What you are saying in this query is this:

```
UPDATE intra_staff SET br_code = (82 AND staff_code = 2918)
```

`(82 and staff_code = 2918)` will become true (or `1`) for `staff_code` 2918, but false (`0`) in every other case. You are setting this outcome (0 or 1) to `br_code`

Depending on what you want, you use this query to set the `br_code` to 82 for `staff_code` 2918:

```
UPDATE intra_staff SET br_code = 82 WHERE staff_code = 2918
```

Or if you want to set every row to `br_code` 82 and `staff_code` to 2918:

```
UPDATE intra_staff SET br_code = 82, staff_code = 2918
```